# Should a class validate argument using external method/service with unit testing?

Tags: c#, tdd, single-responsibility

I have a class that runs as a service and returns html code of a website when supplied with a URL.

The code:

```
public interface IHtmlDownloader
{
    IWebProxy Proxy { get; set; }
    string UserAgent { get; set; }

    string GetHtml(string url)
}

public class HtmlDownloader : IHtmlDownloader
{
    WebClient _client;

    public IWebProxy Proxy
    {
        get { return _client.Proxy; }
        set { _client.Proxy = value; }
    }

    public string UserAgent
    {
        get
        { return _client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent].ToString(); }
        set
        { _client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = value; }
    }

    public HtmlDownloder()
    {
        _client = new WebClient();
    }

    public string GetHtml(string url)
    {
        this.CheckValidity(url);

        var htmlOfWebsite = _client.DownloadString(url);

        return htmlOfWebsite;
    }
}
```

Now I am not sure how exactly I should validate the URL. I know that it should not be null or whitespace or anything else, but should I validate that it is indeed a properly built URL?

Doing so would result in a method which would perform the validation. I could simply [create a public static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337494/should-callers-check-validity-of-arguments-before-calling-constructor) inside `HtmlDownloader` so that the caller can validate the URL, or maybe even not a static one (`GetUrl(string url)` is after all called after the object has been instantiated), but it would be wrong for at least two reasons:

1. It would be a validator applicable in so many places, and it should be available to other classes.
2. I can't contract a static method with an interface.

Furthermore, it shouldn't be made static, but rather a service, so I could unit test `HtmlDownloader` (service would be injected through the constructor).

All of those ideas are quite dreadful and I am starting to think, that I shouldn't validate anything, but simply create a `try/catch` block that would catch the proper exception and then throw a UrlNotFoundException with the original exception supplied through InnerException.

Still, it would be nice to check for the validity of the URL. But to whom and how? Should the caller be injected with the proper service? But then, what if the URL is generated higher than the caller and the caller simply passes it on to the HtmlDownloader? Where should I validate the URL? Or is the simple fact that the URL have to passed through a few levels a code smell?

Comment: The .NET world has the System.Uri (I think, off the top of my head) class which will validate and handle uri's for you.

Comment: While this is true, Uri can be anything -- from `mailto:` to `ftp:` to a local destination. Since I want to be sure that it's a `http:` or `https:` Uri.

Comment: System.Uri will tell you that via the Scheme property. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.scheme%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, I know, that's what my method does. Isn't it better to create a generic method out of it? And further: who should validate the URL?

Comment: IMO opinion the service should validate the URL so that it can return an error describing the misuse.  You can't rely on the caller running validation and ensuring it passes you valid parameters.  Validation of generic properties should be handled with a generic mechanism.  If your language provides you with the construct then use it directly in this code.  If it's not available I'd say implement one that can be called statically and call that instead - I.E. treat it as if it was a standard language construct.

Comment: @RobBaillie, I'm probably overreacting (I'm still very green), but what about TDD? It seems tempting to do so -- treat some methods/classes as if they were a part of the language, but which methods/classes could be treated that way? P.S. I'd +1, but for some reason cannot.

Comment: If you implemented a URL validator (or wrapped the available language construct to make it nicer to use) there is no reason why this couldn't be tested exhaustively. The test for the service need only then test that some validation exists and assume that the otherwise tested validator was used.  You *could* get into the world of a configuration driven set of validation classes that lend themselves particularly to testing if you build a few services, but something like that may be overkill for a single service like this.

Comment: I don't know if I got it right. By saying "the test should assume that validation exist", do you mean that when testing `HtmlDownloader`, the validator will be tested at the same time, since it will be there, not passed into the class through dependency injection, but used directly in the code. And that that's OK. Right?

Comment: If this is the only service you're implementing then I'd probably go simple.  In HtmlDownloader you can call a static method and then test the validation enough to convince yourself that you are calling it (an obviously valid email address passes, an obviously invalid email address fails).  The static validation method can then be tested independently.  Dependency injection isn't always appropriate.  IMO it is the HtmlDownloader's responsibility to define that it requires a valid URL, not the thing constructing it.

Comment: If you're creating multiple services then you should probably implement something like a validator that runs off a configuration.  You can then inject the `Validator` into the `HtmlDownloader` and it would pass it a configuration saying (for example - pseudocode) `{ url: { required: true, type: ValidationType.URL } }` and the passed in data.  The implementation lives outside the `HtmlDownloader`, but the specification of the parameter types lives in the service.  However - this would probably be overkill for just one or two services.  It a question of scale and required flexibility.

Comment: In order to reduce the number of future comments I have moved this into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the service should validate the URL so that it can return an error describing the misuse. You can't rely on the caller running validation and ensuring it passes you valid parameters.  I imagine that's probably taken as read and you weren't suggesting that the thing calling the service defines the validation.

Moving on, validation of generic properties should be handled with a generic mechanism.

**Assuming first of all that you're implementing a small number of services:**

If your language provides you with the construct then use it directly in this code.

If it's not available I'd say implement one that can be called statically and call that instead - I.E. treat it as if it was a standard language construct.

It's simple and straightforward and only starts to cause a problem if you have a lot of services and a lot of duplication.

In terms of TDD:

Let's say you implemented the static method `UrlValidator::validate` - either it's a full blown implementation or it wraps up the available language construct to make it nicer to use.  That's not important - it's just a static method.

This can be tested exhaustively in its own unit test.  You can throw a thousand test cases at it to make sure it behaves exactly as you require.

Then, when you are testing the service `HtmlDownloader` you then only need to test the validation enough to convince yourself that you are correctly using the `UrlValidator`.  For example, ensure an obviously valid email address passes, an obviously invalid email address fails.

This is kind of similar to what you would do with Dependency Injection except you have an assumption - you test enough to convince yourself that your assumption is correct.  With DI you directly test that the assumption is correct.

And fair enough, DI might make this a little easier to test and the test more robust, but it seems like overkill for such a simple issue - particularly if you are only implementing a small number of services.

In my opinion it should be `HtmlDownloader`s responsiblity to define that it needs a valid URL, and if that's the case it's not just the case of injecting a `UrlValidator`, but of injecting something that can validate whatever you ask it to.

**Which leads me onto to the "if you're implementing a lot of services" case.**

In this situation it is probably worthwhile implementing a generic parameter validation package.  Something that you can inject into `HtmlDownloader`, so that it can pass in a configuration and the data received and get back a validation state.

E.g. you might pass in something like (pseudo-code):

```
{ url = { required = true
        , dataType = ValidationTypes::URL }
}
```

The implementation of the validation lives outside the service, but the service cleanly defines what needs to be validated, and what the requirements are.

This massively reduces the testing required because you now only need to test that the configuration is correct, rather than testing the effect of it.

I like implementations like this, it's just that it's sometimes overkill for the kind of solution you need.

It a question of scale and required flexibility.

Answer (score -1):

As much as possible try and make your classes as independent as possible during unit testing, keeping cross referencing of functions down to a minimum will help in debugging, after all unit testing is done you could then create standalone utility functions that can handle operations that will be cross referenced by your classes...